# Firebase: User.photoUrl to String

Tags: javascript, firebase, web

I'm trying to store all the user's profile photos in the realtime database, but I'm stucked with a problem.

When trying to upload the PhotoUrl with this code, this error shows up.

**Code:**

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.updateProfile({

  // Here, "name" and "imgUrl" are parameters of parent function.
  // I don't think this is the reason, but if it helps,
  // "imgUrl" always come from a <img> src.
  displayName: name,
  photoUrl: imgUrl

}).then(function(){

  // Here is where I try to upload all to the database
  firebase.database().ref("/Usuarios/" + user.uid).set({
    "email": email,
    "name": name,
    "photoUri": user.photoUrl, // This is where I think the problem originates.
    "uid": user.uid  // This calls user again, and it works perfectly.
  });

});
```

**Error:**

```
Uncaught Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'Usuarios.kD1tD1NAmsaGiW0zj6lFz9GDWro1.photoUri'.
```

When I do *alert(user.photoUrl)*, it shows as 'undefined'.

The first thing I thought was that it can't be saved in database because it isn't a String, so I tried calling toString() from it, but I can't.

**toString() error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

---

So, how can I save the photoUrl from a user (as String) in Firebase Database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I had the same issue today and I realized that I was trying to reference as `photoUrl` but the correct is `photoURL`, notice the capitalized URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most I tried not to do this type of workarounds, ended up **uploading the photo to Firebase Storage, then setting *User.photoURL* and *"photoUri"* DB field to the url of the uploaded image**:

```
user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
avatarStgRef = firebase.storage().ref("Usuarios/" + user.uid + "/avatar.jpg");

// imgFile the Photo File.
avatarStgRef.put(imgFile).then(function(snapshot){
    snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(url){  // Now I can use url
        user.updateProfile({
            photoURL: url       // <- URL from uploaded photo.
        }).then(function(){
            firebase.database().ref("Usuarios/" + user.uid).set({
              "photoUri": url   // <- URL from uploaded photo.
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [photoUrl](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#photoURL) is a nullable string as you can see in the documentation.

So you have to test if the value is set before use it.

For example :

```
if (typeof user.photoUrl != 'undefined') {
    // Use user.photoUrl
}
```

Comment: Yes, it will surely prevent any errors, but _photoUrl_ is always 'undefined'. I need to put it on database. I'm looking for a way to do it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: To have a photoUrl by default you need to authenticate the user with a social provider like facebook, twiter or google. Else you need to set it yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose there's a problem with the _imgUrl_ I want to put as User.photoURL. Anyway, I used FirebaseStorage to get a "secure" URL of the image. Thanks for your responses!